# RPM build failed - could not find any valid magic files

Tags: rpm, package-managers, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I was generating RPM for one of my project, but while processing RPM it displays error as below,

```
file: could not find any valid magic files! 
file: could not find any valid magic files!
file: could not find any valid magic files! 
file: could not find any valid magic files!
file: could not find any valid magic files!
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-python-bytecompile /usr/bin/python 1
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-python-hardlink
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-java-repack-jars 
Processing files: DEV_SAMPLE-1.0-1.el7.x86_64 unknown, 0: Warning: using regular magic file `/bin/share/misc/magic' error: magic_load failed: could not find any valid magic files!

RPM build errors:
    magic_load failed: could not find any valid magic files!
```

Operating system : CentOS Linux 7.4, and I already have magic files in my system.
How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

To do certain things like run `strip` on executables, `rpmbuild` uses the standard Linux command `file`. It sounds like your install of it is somehow corrupted; it uses what it calls a "magic file" that has hints on how to identify different files based on their contents. You can try it with `file $(which file)` and it *should* say something like `x86_64 ELF Executable`.

You can check its install explicitly with `sudo rpm -V file`. (I'm not on a CentOS box right now so cannot confirm that's the package name - `rpm -q --whatprovides $(which file)` can tell you if I'm wrong.) That command should return *nothing*; if it shows any files, they are likely corrupted or missing.

To reinstall / fix your install of `file`, `sudo yum reinstall file` (or whatever the package is if I was wrong).

Comment: You're right about stripping, during RPM creation process, binary files are stripped to reduce the size without affecting the original functionality. rpmbuild uses the builtin compression script defined in macro  __os_install_post to perform these operation. we just need to disable this using  %global __os_install_post %{nil}. Thanks

Comment: The `os_post_install` does other things too; that is one way to fix it. I'd be concerned as to why the `file` install was corrupted tho.

Comment: Based on the warning `unknown, 0: Warning: using regular magic file /bin/share/misc/magic` , It's trying to load magic files from the path `/bin/share/misc/magic` which is not the default installed magic file path. Any clue?

Comment: No idea, sorry. `rpm -ql` should show the files it _should_ have installed.